# How old were Rochel and Leah when they got married to Yaakov?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, age, imahot-matriarch-mothers

To my recollection I have never seen an answer to this or have known anything regarding Rochel and Leah's ages at marriage. Are they known?